# rank 1 projectiom

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection

A projection $p$ is called the rank 1 projection on a Hilbert space $H$ if $p=x\otimes x$ for some unit vector $x$

Suppose $q$ is any non-trivial projection on $H$,does there exsit a relationship between $q$ and rank 1 projections?
 Can $q$ be experessed by linear combinations of rank 1 projections?

Comment: Is $q$ suppose to ab orthogonal projection on a closed subspace?

Comment: $q$ satisfies the following condition $q=q^2=q^*.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the range of $q$ an d let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $M$. Then any vector $x$ can be written as $x =\sum a_ne_n+y$ with $ y \in M^{\perp}$ and we have $qx=\sum a_n e_n$. If $q_i$ is the rank $1$ projection with range $span \{e_i\}$ the we can write $qx=\sum q_nx$. it is not possible to write $q$ in terms of a  finite number rank $1$ projections.

Comment: what about "approxiamtion by rank 1 projections?"

Comment: I don 't know what type of approximation you are talking about. In you can approximate $q$ in strong topology by a finite sum of rank $1$ operators.

Comment: No. Any limit in operator norm of finite rank operators is a compact operator. A projection operator is never a compact operator unless it is itself a finite rank operator. In other words no projection with infinite dimensional range can be approximated  in operator norm by a finite sum  of  rank $1$ operators.